in gmail compose, loading of new signature updated via gmail app or appscript addon does not work unless gmail page is refreshed
The requirement is to use a dynamic signature as soon as Gmail default compose button is clicked.
Option 1:
Tried with below to set the signature. It does so, but then unless I reload the Gmail page, doesnt get the new signatures which have been updated via App triggers.
Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.patch(newSig, "me", Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())

Basically above sets the signature (which I can see in manage signatures), and then it just doesnt update this unless I refresh.
Option 2:
Tried using addOns.gmail.contextualTrigger. But the method defined in this just doesnt seem to get called.
The method defined in  addOns.gmail.composeTrigger.selectActions.runFunction does get called and shows the logo and then this updates the signature if clicked. But I don't want this extra click.

Sounds like you are having a problem with Gmail UI.  We have not control over that.
